# Submit jobs via Rest API and deploy Flink on a running Kubernetes cluster (Native way)

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

I am trying to implement a Rest client for Flink to send jobs via Restful Flink services. And also I want to integrate Flink and Kubernetes natively. I have decided to use “Application Mode” as deployment mode according to Flink documentation .
I have already implemented a job and packaged it as jar. And I have tested it on Standalone Flink. But my aim is to move on Kubernetes and deploy my application in Application mode via Rest API of Flink.

I have already investigated the samples at Flink documentation - Native Kubernetes. But I cannot find a sample for executing same samples via Restful services (esp. how to set --target kubernetes-application/kubernetes-session or other parameters).

In addition to samples, I checked out the Flink sources from GitHub and tried to find some sample implementation or get some clue.
I think the below ones are related with my case.

- org.apache.flink.client.program.rest. RestClusterClient
- org.apache.flink.kubernetes. KubernetesClusterDescriptorTest. testDeployApplicationCluster

But they are all so complicated for me to understand below points.

- For application mode, are there any need to initialize a container to serve Flink Rest services before submitting job? If so, is it JobManager?
- For application mode, how can I set the same command line parameters via Rest services?
- For session mode, in command line samples, kubernetes-session.sh is executed before job submission to initialize a JobManager container. How sould I do this step via Rest client?
- For session mode, how can I set the same command line parameters via Rest services? Although the command line samples send .jar job as parameter, should I upload jar before submitting job?

Could you please provide me some clue/sample to continue my implementation?

Best regards,
Burcu

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that if you study the implementation of the [Apache Flink Kubernetes Operator](https://flink.apache.org/news/2022/04/03/release-kubernetes-operator-0.1.0.html) you'll find some clues.